# Heroku not respecting PHP requirement in composer.json

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

Although I have set php requirements to exactly what the heroku docs suggest here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support, heroku still deploys my app using PHP 7.0.

I have commited both the composer.json and composer.lock as required.

Any ideas how I can fix this other than upgrading my code to work with PHP7.0 ?

Comment: can you post your composer.json file content?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug that we're working to address in the buildpack - I see some commits to the BP lastnight to fix - try again?

Comment: Absolutely, after talking to the heroku support it was quickly evident this was an issue with the php buildpack.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an issue with the Heroku php buildpack. Support was very cooperative and pushed a fix to the buildpack last night.

The problem was related to how the buildpack treated operator precedence.